# Unable to serve a Ionic Creator App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, localhost

I just made a Ionic Creator App which I exported with:

```
$ionic start [Appname] creator:[App-ID]
```

Then I wanted to run it with:

```
$ionic serve
```

But I got the following Error Message:

Error output while serving an Ionic App:

[image: Error output while serving an Ionic App]

I am using the Bash on Windows Command Line.

Does anybody know what is wrong here?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic servce default uses localhost, is your APP run on a virtual OS?
You may try adding --address YOUR_IP to the end.

```
ionic run android --livereload --consolelogs --address 192.168.0.7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had no chance to try it, because in the meantime I solved it in another way. I am on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. The problem was that my windows build was too old, causing the error above. Logging in to Windows Insider and downloading the latest build solved the Problem, because it has some extra features, which were not available before,